# Typescript AMD Modules in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript

I am starting with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I have changed my MSBuild including the --module amd tag in the compiler command. The compiler started to generate AMD modules.

I have include in my project RequireJS from Nuget Packages and include in my main HTML this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="scripts/SiteMaster"  src="scripts/require.min.js"></script>
```

I have two Modules SiteMaster and Authenticate. The module SiteMaster is simple:

```
export module SiteMaster {
    import auth = module("Authenticate");
    auth.Authenticate.run();
}
```

It just imports the Authenticate module and calls the function run(). The js for SiteMaster is like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
(function (SiteMaster) {
    var auth = __auth__;

    auth.Authenticate.run();
})(exports.SiteMaster || (exports.SiteMaster = {}));
```

})

The problem is that when I browse the solution I receive the error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: '__auth__' is undefined
```

How can I solve this problem ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty much convinced that this is an error in the compiler. I have reproduced the issue using the following source files:

**Authenticate.ts**

```
export var Authenticate = { 
    run : function() {
        console.log("Run!");
    }
}
```

**SiteMaster.ts**

```
export module SiteMaster {
    import auth = module("Authenticate");
    auth.Authenticate.run();
}
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="SiteMaster"  src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.0/minified/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I compile the typescripts using

```
tsc --module amd SiteMaster.ts Authenticate.ts
```

When I open the `test.html` in Firefox with Firebug, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: __auth__ is not defined
var auth = __auth__;
```

The compiled code for `SiteMaster.js` looks as follows:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    (function (SiteMaster) {
        var auth = __auth__;

        auth.Authenticate.run();
    })(exports.SiteMaster || (exports.SiteMaster = {}));

})
```

Judging from TypeScript's language specification section *9.4.3 AMD Modules* I would expect something along the lines of:

```
define(["require", "exports", "authenticate"], function(require, exports, authenticateModule) {
    (function (SiteMaster) {
        var auth = authenticateModule;

        auth.Authenticate.run();
    })(exports.SiteMaster || (exports.SiteMaster = {}));

})
```

This is in line with the examples in the language specification. If others agree, we might submit a bug with the TypeScript team.

Comment: I Agree. Go Ahead Valentin. Submit the bug.

Comment: @mvbaffa It seems like Murat already submitted a bug at the typescript site.

Comment: @Valentin could you provide a link to said bug? TIA

Comment: @Anzeo I was trying to find the issue but unfortunately could not find it.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for bringing this up mvbaffa!

On Valentin's sample if you change SiteMaster.ts to:

```
import auth = module("Authenticate");
export module SiteMaster {
    auth.Authenticate.run();
}
```

by moving the import statement out of the module declaration it will generate the correct js code. I'll open a bug on the TypeScript codeplex site and make sure this gets fixed. You can do the workaround on the current compiler [v0.8] if this is a blocking issue for you.

Comment: It worked. Unfortunatelly I cannot use the answer to show the generated code, StackOverflow does not allow me. I am not so graduated. Anyway Thank you very much.