# How can I define dependent modules in TypeScript AMD Modules

Tags: typescript

How can I define the dependent modules in a AMD Module with TypeScript, including, for instance, jQuery and underscore. Using JavaScript I do, for example, like this:

```
define('moduleA',
    ['jquery', 'underscore'], function ($, _) {
    }
});
```

How can do this so that TypeScript compiler generates this code.

Comment: Remember, you can grab the definition of RequireJS and use it directly in your TypeScript code. http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201302/Blog/Using-RequireJS-and-Jquery-In-TypeScript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current implementation of the compiler (0.8) the way to achieve what you are seeking is the following.

test.ts:

```
import jquery = module("jquery");
import underscore = module("underscore");

export module A {
    console.log(jquery.$ + underscore._);
}
```

jquery.ts:

```
export var $ = null;
```

underscore.ts:

```
export var _ = null;
```

if you compile test.ts using the module switch:

```
tsc --module AMD test.ts
```

it will generate the following JS file for you:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery", "underscore"], function(require, exports, __jquery__, __underscore__) {
    var jquery = __jquery__;
    var underscore = __underscore__;
    (function (A) {
        console.log(jquery.$ + underscore._);
    })(exports.A || (exports.A = {}));
})
```

Note that if you put import statements inside the module it will note codegen correctly due to a bug. The team is currently working on a fix on that item but hopefully that shouldn't block you.

Comment: Ok. I will try as soon as I can access my development machine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This currently does not work correctly in typescript due to a bug in the compiler (see [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762462/typescript-amd-modules-in-visual-studio)). What you would need to do is define a module `moduleA` that imports `jquery` and `underscore`, and then compile that with `-module amd`. Basically, you would need the following three files:

**moduleA.ts**

```
export module moduleA {
    import jquery = module("jquery");
    import underscore = module("underscore");
    console.log(jquery.jquery);
    console.log(underscore.underscore);
}
```

**jquery.ts**

```
export module jquery {
    var jquery = "jquery";
}
```

**underscore.ts**

```
export module underscore {
    var underscore = "underscore";
}
```

Compiling those three files with `tsc -module amd` yields the following code for `moduleA.js`:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    (function (moduleA) {
        var jquery = __jquery__;

        var underscore = __underscore__;

        console.log(jquery.jquery);
        console.log(underscore.underscore);
    })(exports.moduleA || (exports.moduleA = {}));

})
```

Like I said above, due to a bug in the compiler, this code is actually incorrect and will complain about missing `__jquery__` at runtime. However, once this bug is fixed the `amd` loader of `node.js` should be able to load the modules.